# Are these enough to research in Algebraic Number Theory?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

$ \text{Algebraic Number Theory:}$

To do research in Algebraic Number Theory what are the essential topics to know?

I have basic knowledge in Abstract Algebra, Topology and Analysis as well as the number fields $ \mathbb{Q}, \ \mathbb{R}, \ \mathbb{C}$.

I do not have much knowledge in Analytic Number Theory.

Are these enough to research in Algebraic Number Theory?

If somebody can give advice me regarding the above questions.

Also please tell me  some best book in Algebraic Number Theory.

Thanks,

Comment: If by "usual knowledge" of Abstract algebra you mean Basic Group Theory, Ring Theory (in particular polynomial rings), Fields extensions and basic Galois Theory, and of course also Linear Algebra, then yes: that seems to be enough to tackle basic Algebraic Number Theory. Now, for **research** I'd say much more is needed: some basic Analytic Number Theory and Complex Analysis will surely help.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Yes I mean basic knowledge.  Many thanks for your important suggestion

Comment: I think you will need number theory also.

Comment: From my student perspective I'd say in number theory there are two kind of papers : those with a lot of asymptotic estimates in order to derive and refine some error terms in analytic number theory, and those with a lot of theoretical objects appearing in the theory of Galois representations, automorphic forms, varieties, cohomology, class field theory.

Comment: I'd recommend trying 1 or 2 books on Algebraic Number Theory (there are PDF's online) and ... if there is something you don't understand in those books, that will be the gap you have to cover.

Comment: Yes I have some book on ANT . For example,  a book by Neukric, a book by F. Oggier,  a book by M. Ram Murty.